# Differential Equation with $f'(t)=\cos(f(t))$ prove that $-2 < f(t) < 2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I cannot solve the following exercise:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be infinetly often differentiable with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(t)=\cos(f(t))$.

Prove that $-2 < f(t) < 2 $ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I saw that $|f'(t) \leq 1|$ and tried applying mean value theorem for $0$ and $t$ but still couldn't find a solution. I also tried to integrate but still could only show that $f(t) \leq t$.

Comment: Apply $\cos(\pm\frac\pi2)=0$.

Comment: @ Cake: Range for $f (x)$ may be $\pm \pi/2$ instead of $\pm2$. Can you mention the source of the problem or  the book reference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0)| \ge 2$. For simplicity, let's assume that $f(x_0) \ge 2$ (the case $f(x_0) \le 2$ can be treated similarly). Since $f(0) = 0$, there must a point $x_1$ such that $$f(x_1) \in \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, 2 \right) \qquad \& \qquad f(x_1) > 0.$$ Notice that this is in contradiction with $f'(x_1) = \cos(f(x_1)) < 0$.

A few comments:

1. Observe that there is nothing special about the number $2$. Indeed, the same argument can be used to show that $|f(x)| \le \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. To do this, once again arguing by contradiction, assume that there is $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0)| = \tfrac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. The argument above then continues to work by replacing $2$ with $\tfrac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon$.
2. This is not surprising since, roughly speaking, the ODE for $f$ tells you that ``$f$ starts decreasing as soon as it goes over $\pi/2$, and increasing once it crosses the line $y = -\pi/2$''.
3. You can push the inequality even further to $|f(x)| < \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. Indeed, you can prove that if $f(x) = \pm \tfrac{\pi}{2}$ for some $x$, then $f$ must be constant and everywhere equal to $\pm \tfrac{\pi}{2}$ (thus giving a contradiction with the assumption that $f(0) = 0$).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{df(t)}{dt}=\cos f(t)$
$\implies \sec f(t) df(t)=dt$
$\implies \ln|\cot \left (\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{f(t)}{2}\right )|=t+c$ (On integration)
Use initial condition $f(0)=0$ to get $c=0$ so that

$\cot \left (\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{f(t)}{2}\right )=e^t$
$\implies \tan \left (\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{f(t)}{2}\right )=e^{-t}$
$\implies \frac{1-\tan(f(t)/2)}{1+\tan(f(t)/2)}=e^{-t}$
$\implies -\tan (f(t)/2)=\frac{ e^{-t}-1}{e^{-t}+1}$
$\implies f(t)=2\tan^{-1}\left (\frac{1- e^{-t}}{e^{-t}+1}\right )$
Now
$\left (\frac{1- e^{-t}}{e^{-t}+1}\right )=1-\frac{2}{e^t+1}$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ so you get the inequality
$2\tan^{-1}(-1)<f(t)<2\tan^{-1}(1)$ or $-\pi/2<f(t)<\pi/2$

Comment: I get the same solution !

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

I get range limits $\pm \pi/2$  instead of $\pm 2$. Let $y=f(t)$ and by direct integration:

$$\int \sec y ~dy =\log \tan (\pi/4 +y/2)= t+C$$

With given boundary conditions $C=0$

$$ y(t)= 2 \tan^{-1}(e^t)- \pi/2$$

$$t \to  \infty , y \to \pi/2,~~ t \to  -\infty , y \to -\pi/2.$$

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation is similar to the description of the angle in [Simple gravity pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#Simple_gravity_pendulum).
A nice idea to approximate the ODE is to take a small angle here, a small $f\left( x \right)$ value. But we can find a closed form too.

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} = \cos\left( f\left( x \right) \right).\\
\end{align*}
$$
We see straight away that the equation is a wonderful case of a *Separable Equation*. Taking $\left( \cdot \right)^{-1}$ of both sides gives us:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)} &= \frac{1}{\cos\left( f\left( x \right) \right)}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)} &= \sec\left( f\left( x \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

If we multiply both sides by $\operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{d}x &= \sec\left( f\left( x \right) \right) \cdot \operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)\\
\int 1\, \operatorname{d}x &= \int \sec\left( f\left( x \right) \right)\, \operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)\\
x + c_{1} &= \ln\left( \frac{\sin\left( f\left( x \right) \right) + 1}{\cos\left( f\left( x \right) \right)} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

---

Problem: Solving $x + c_{1} = \ln\left( \frac{\sin\left( f\left( x \right) \right) + 1}{\cos\left( f\left( x \right) \right)} \right)$.
This is quite hard. We know $\frac{\sin\left( x \right)}{\cos\left( x \right) + 1} = \tan\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$, so:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos\left( x \right) + 1}{\sin\left( x \right)} &= \cot\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)\\
\frac{\sin\left( x \right) + 1}{\cos\left( x \right)} &= -\cot\left( \frac{x - \frac{\pi}{2}}{2} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

We get:
$$
\begin{align*}
x + c_{1} &= \ln\left( -\cot\left( \frac{f\left( x \right) - \frac{\pi}{2}}{2} \right) \right)\\
e^{x + c_{1}} &= -\cot\left( \frac{f\left( x \right) - \frac{\pi}{2}}{2} \right)\\
\operatorname{arccot}\left( -e^{x + c_{1}} \right) &= \frac{f\left( x \right) - \frac{\pi}{2}}{2}\\
2 \cdot \operatorname{arccot}\left( -e^{x + c_{1}} \right) + \frac{\pi}{2} &= f\left( x \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Solution:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
f\left( x \right) &= 2 \cdot \operatorname{arccot}\left( c_{2} \cdot e^{x} \right) + \frac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

[Wolfram|Alpha checks that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282%20*%20arccot%28-e%5Ex%29%20%2B%20pi%2F2%29%27%3Dcos%282%20*%20arccot%28-e%5Ex%29%20%2B%20pi%2F2%29): [True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYFNF.png)

I've tried several ways to derive a solution, but this is the simplest I've found. Wolfram|Alpha proposes two other solutions (they are the same solutions but written differently and more complicated). But apart from the fact that the solution is simpler, the solution is also faster to derive from me. But there is still a solution missing, the constant one ($k \ in \mathbb{Z}$):
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} = \cos\left( f\left( x \right) \right)\\
0 = \cos\left( f\left( x \right) \right)\\
\arccos\left( 0 \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi = f\left( x \right)\\
\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi = f\left( x \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$